# Oracle service bus 11G REST api Java is having socket issue when connecting to OSB

Tags: java, rest, sockets, oracle11g

im done setting REST api on oracle service bus 11g. i tried the test console on OSB and it works fine and returning result on JSON format. But the problem comes when im calling REST api on JAVA.

Please click hyperlink below to see error message and code

[the URL that i fired is URL of OSB proxy service, then it will call to REST URL endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwUyR.png)

The error i got:
[it shows socket exception and related to the input stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtUGt.png)

Comment: Close the connection after completing the task.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb i got put a "conn.disconnect();" after i read the request. But the log shows like the error happened after http get the response from other end come back when java reading the response "BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));"

Comment: share some code snippet

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya please click on the hyperlink above

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
LOGGER.info(conn.getResponseMessage());
```

and change the `Accept`

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Then just do

```
if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("HTTP Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

// . . .

conn.disconnect();
```

If you are still getting issues, then it means that the request you are sending through code is not the same as the browser.  To resolve this, check the request details in the browser and that the request header is perfectly matching the one in code, including `User-Agent`, `POST`/`GET`.  You can listen to the network.  There are many tools to help you identify the HTTP request details.